# Can't track events of Looker Embedded Dashborard (SSO embedded) in Nest.JS application

Tags: next.js, event-tracking, looker

I have next.js project, on server side I generate Looker-sso url and on client side I use this url for embedded dashboard.

Here is how I generate SSO url at Next.js server side

```
function getLookerSsoUrl(embeddedUserParams: UserInfo, dashboardId: string) : string {
    /** Returns Looker Embedded sso url. */

    const url_data : LookerEmbeddedUrlOptions = {
        "host": LOOKER_HOST,
        "secret": LOOKER_SECRET,
        "first_name": embeddedUserParams.firstName,
        "last_name": embeddedUserParams.lastName,
        "external_user_id": embeddedUserParams.firstName + " " + embeddedUserParams.lastName,
        "external_group_id": embeddedUserParams.companyName + " group",
        "group_ids": [1],
        "access_filters": {},
        "models": ['db_analytics'],
        "permissions": [
            'see_user_dashboards',
            'see_lookml_dashboards',
            'access_data',
            'see_looks'],
        "user_attributes": {
            "name": embeddedUserParams.firstName + " " + embeddedUserParams.lastName,
            "first_name": embeddedUserParams.firstName,
            "last_name": embeddedUserParams.lastName,
            "email": embeddedUserParams.email,
            "company_id": embeddedUserParams.companyId,
            "company_name": embeddedUserParams.companyName,
            "id": embeddedUserParams.id
        },
        "session_length": 15 * 60,
        "embed_url": `/embed/dashboards/${dashboardId}?embed_domain=http://localhost&company_id=${embeddedUserParams.companyId}`,
        "force_logout_login": true
    }

    return "https://" + getSignedEmbedUrl(url_data)
}

function getSignedEmbedUrl(options : LookerEmbeddedUrlOptions) : string {
    /** Build sso url with all Looker options and secret key and returns it. */

        // looker options
    const secret = options.secret
    const host = options.host

    // user options
    const json_external_user_id = JSON.stringify(options.external_user_id)
    const json_first_name = JSON.stringify(options.first_name)
    const json_last_name = JSON.stringify(options.last_name)
    const json_permissions = JSON.stringify(options.permissions)
    const json_models = JSON.stringify(options.models)
    const json_group_ids = JSON.stringify(options.group_ids)
    const json_external_group_id = JSON.stringify(options.external_group_id || "")
    const json_user_attributes = JSON.stringify(options.user_attributes || {})
    const json_access_filters = JSON.stringify(options.access_filters)

    // url/session specific options
    const embed_path = '/login/embed/' + encodeURIComponent(options.embed_url)
    const json_session_length = JSON.stringify(options.session_length)
    const json_force_logout_login = JSON.stringify(options.force_logout_login)

    // computed options
    const json_time = JSON.stringify(Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000))
    const json_nonce = JSON.stringify(getNonce(16))

    // compute signature
    let string_to_sign = ""
    string_to_sign += host + "\n"
    string_to_sign += embed_path + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_nonce + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_time + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_session_length + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_external_user_id + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_permissions + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_models + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_group_ids + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_external_group_id + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_user_attributes + "\n"
    string_to_sign += json_access_filters

    const signature = createHmac('sha1', secret).update(ForceUnicodeEncoding(string_to_sign)).digest('base64').trim()

    // construct query string
    const query_params = {
        nonce: json_nonce,
        time: json_time,
        session_length: json_session_length,
        external_user_id: json_external_user_id,
        permissions: json_permissions,
        models: json_models,
        access_filters: json_access_filters,
        first_name: json_first_name,
        last_name: json_last_name,
        group_ids: json_group_ids,
        external_group_id: json_external_group_id,
        user_attributes: json_user_attributes,
        force_logout_login: json_force_logout_login,
        signature: signature
    }

    const query_string = stringify(query_params)

    return host + embed_path + '?' + query_string
}


function getNonce(len : number) : string {
    /** Returns nonce characters. */

    let text = ""
    const possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))

    return text
}

function ForceUnicodeEncoding(string : string) : string {
    /** Decodes a URI component previously created by encodeURIComponent. */

    return decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(string))
}
```

Here is client side code:

```
import React, {useCallback} from "react"
import {LookerEmbedSDK} from "@looker/embed-sdk"
import {ENV_VAR} from "env"

type embeddedDashboardType = {
    id : number
    setError? :  ((errorMsg : string) => void)
}

export const EmbeddedDashboard = ({id, setError} : embeddedDashboardType) => {
    const canceller = (event : any) => {
        return { cancel: !event.modal }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", ()=>console.log("r"))

    const embedCtrRef = useCallback((el) => {
        const authUrl = "/api/looker-sso"

        if (el) {
            LookerEmbedSDK.init("...", authUrl)
            LookerEmbedSDK.createDashboardWithId(id)
                .withNext()
                .appendTo(el)
                .on("drillmenu:click", canceller)
                .on("drillmodal:explore", canceller)
                .on("dashboard:tile:explore", canceller)
                .on("look:ready", ()=> console.log("ready"))
                .on("explore:ready", ()=>console.log("ready"))
                .on("dashboard:run:start", ()=>console.log("ready"))
                .on("dashboard:tile:view", canceller)
                .build()
                .connect()
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Connection error", error)

                    if (setError){
                        setError(error)
                    }
                })
        }
    }, [])

  return <>
    <style jsx>{`
      :global(.container-dashboard) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 95vh;
      }
      :global(.container-dashboard > iframe) {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
      }
    `}</style>
      <div className="container-dashboard" ref={embedCtrRef} />
  </>
}
```

The dashboard displays correctly, but I cant track events, that happen in Looker Iframe

I except, that I would see clicks, which are made on looker iframe